# Base64 encoded String too big, trailing characters truncated in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have an image which I have to convert to `base64`. After the conversion, below is its value:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

and so on...

This a quite a big value. I need to put this in a `char data[]` like below:

```
char sPostData[21070] = "{ \"image\" : \"<base64 encoded value>\"  ,  \"name\": \"dev\"}";
```

but it throws this error:

```
Error   C2026   string too big, trailing characters truncated
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Try it without specifying the size of the array: `char sPostData[] = "{ \"image\" : \"<base64 encoded value>\"  ,  \"name\": \"dev\"}";`. C++ am smart. It can figure out the array size itself.

Comment: @user4581301 No it gives same error

Comment: Huh. Thought c++ had a 64K limit. Have to go spelunking to see if CL has a smaller limit on the size of a string literal it can eat.

Comment: [*The maximum length of a string literal is 65535 bytes. This limit applies to both narrow string literals and wide string literals.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2015)  This goes 2015 through 2019. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @user4581301 I am using vs2017

Comment: Weird. I'm going to drop this one and leave it to the folks who know the Visual Studio toolchain better than I do. Could be some caveat I'm missing.

Comment: @user4581301 That apparently applies to string literals, `const char *`.  `char[]` character arrays have a [different limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2026?view=vs-2019) of 16380 single byte characters.

Comment: According to the documentation for that error, there is a limit of 16380 single-byte characters for a string literal. It also says this is _Prior to adjacent strings being concatenated_, so you may be able to break your string into multiple chunks, something like `char[] = "a whole bunch of characters" "a whole bunch more" "and even more characters"`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm There we go! Thank you. Somebody turn that into a formal answer and ping me for an upvote, please. This is worth recording for posterity. It's for gathering crazy smurf like this that SO was invented.

Comment: @jkb That solved the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Microsoft compiler imposes a limit of 16380 single-byte characters for a string literal. The documentation says

> Prior to adjacent strings being concatenated, a string cannot be longer than 16380 single-byte characters.

Break the string into adjacent chunks, something like

```cpp
char[] = "a whole bunch of characters"
         "a whole bunch more characters"
         " and even more characters";
```

Comment: Or don't use string literals. This probably should be an auto-generated `std::byte[]` initialisation or something

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2026?view=vs-2019) for that error, there is a limit of 16380 bytes in a character array (characters for narrow strings, fewer for Unicode).

Character string pointers (`const char *`) have a [different limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2015), 65535 bytes.